# Can't display overlay

Tags: openlayers-2, overlay

I am trying to add a WMS radar overlay to my map but it won't seem to gather it.

```
  noaaRdr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Latest Radar", "http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/wms/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/obs?", {
    layers: 'RAS_RIDGE_NEXRAD',
    transparent: true,
    format: 'image/png'
  }, {
    visibility: true, isBaseLayer: false, singleTile: true,
    ratio: 1,opacity: 0.7
  });


  radarArray = [noaaRdr];     //adding more layers later..
  map.addLayers(radarArray);
```

I have seen this URL used elsewhere but i can't figure out whats wrong.  The layer shows up in the layer switcher but the image never shows on the map and the file "obs" never gets requested from the NOAA server ??

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Can you use something like Fiddler to see what requests are being sent out by OpenLayers? I can't see anything wrong with your code so it might help to see what request is being sent by OpenLayers and what response you are getting from the server.

Comment: I am developing from a Mac so that is not really an option for me.  Is their a mac equivalent ??

Comment: The closest equivalent that I am aware of is Wireshark - http:// www.wireshark.org

Comment: For debuggin in Mac you can use development tools: https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html

Comment: @MB. have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hi, not solved but I'm thinking it might be my computer as the links that were added as solutions below don't work either  ???? they show the map but not the overlay

Comment: Open link from my post and wait a little bit - layer data need to be downloaded.

Comment: Yes,  It takes a long time to get that data I will try your code verbatim but I think it could be an openlayers issue as I never see the URL request happen inside the web inspector under safari.  Nor do  i see an error in the console log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working code:

```js
options = {
    div: "map",
    zoom: 5,
    center: [-10796366.372312, 4426748.6429884],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
    ],
    projection: "EPSG:3857"
};
map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);

var noaaRdr = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "Latest Radar",
    "http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/wms/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/obs?",
    {
        layers: 'RAS_RIDGE_NEXRAD',
        transparent: true
    },
    {
        isBaseLayer: false,
        singleTile: true,
        opacity: 0.7
    }
);

map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
map.addLayer(noaaRdr);
```

Live example [HERE](http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/obs.html).

Comment: Another example http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/maps/jessica-groups.html

Comment: that example doesn't show radar for me....

Comment: doesn't work using firefox either ??

Comment: Ok So downloaded the latest version of openLayers 2-12 and deleted all the previous files from my website and added the new just in case it was related to that no fix.  one difference is that the projection you are using is   projection: "EPSG:3857"  could it be that ???

Comment: From GetCapabilities response: http://nowcoast.noaa.gov/wms/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/obs?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities you can see that WMS server supports only 3857 and 4326 projections, not 900913, so using EPSG:3857 is mandatory.

Comment: Yippppeeeeee.......  sorry for the delay in commenting but the single reason that mine was not working was that i had not added the layer with the correct projection   projection: "EPSG:3857" my base layers were not using this projection so it would not work.  Thanks much I have shown the answer as correct and voted up..